# SSRS Subscription: Write report to File Share - AND - send Email Notification

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have just switched several Subscriptions from going out via Email - to being written to a Network Folder.

Is there a way [possibly in SSRS?] to:

1. Notify Users by email when the export succeeded

   OR
2. Notify me by email if the export Failed?

Thanks!!

Comment: Would be easier and much more flexible to accomplish this with SSIS.

Comment: @ChrisAlbert: Thanks! I have not worked with SSIS except that I have gone through a couple of Tutorials. Does SSIS come with all installs of SSMS 2012? Does it need to be purchased separately? Can you give me any more information or point me to a thread that covers this? Thanks again!

Comment: [Here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/bi/ssis-in-ssdt-the-basics/) is a great intro tutorial. SSIS is a service that gets installed on the SQL Server alongside the database service and reporting service. [Visual Studio and SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15) are the development tools you will need to install on you development machine.

Comment: Thanks! Greatly appreciated! I will go through the tutorial.